# Jquery success not running when complete ajax call is made

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below you can see I'm making a simple ajax call. However, after the call has successfully completed I would like to remove the loader div from the page. The problem is that the success function does not fire, why?

```
utils.get_do stuff = function AJAX_do stuff() {    
    $.getJSON('/url//',
        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                // I do stuff with the data here.
            });
        },
        function (success) {
            $('#loader').hide();
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) does not accept 2 callback arguments. Read the docs.

Comment: are you trying to _fill_ the data parameter with that first function, or use it to process the AJAX result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an example of  `getJSON`, I think you have to hide the `$('#loader')` in the complete handler, so the `$('#loader')` hides no matter the request fails or succeeds.

```
 $.getJSON( "/sms/fetch_smartpages/", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
         //I do stuff with the data here.
        });
        $('#loader').hide(); //<==== moved from here
    })
    .done(function() { console.log( "second success" ); })
    .fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); })
    .always(function() { 
                console.log( "complete" ); 
                $('#loader').hide(); // moved here
     });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON('/sms/fetch_smartpages/', 

// This callback function is executed if the request succeeds.
function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
     // I do stuff with the data here.
  });

  // Hide loader here
  $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('/sms/fetch_smartpages/',function (data) { // <-- this is your success handler
      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        I do stuff with the data here.
      });
      $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() { console.log( "second success" ); })
.fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); })
.always(function() { console.log( "complete" ); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have misinterpreted the purpose of the second parameter to `$.getJSON()` - it normally contains a JS object used to *supply* data that will be passed to the remote server.

As you've passed a function reference instead that's being used as the "success" callback, and the third parameter is ignored.

If you really want to use two separate "success" callbacks, you can use `.done(f1, f2)`:

```
$.getJSON(...).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            // I do stuff with the data here.
        });
    },
    function (success) {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
);
```

Note that *both* functions will be passed the standard `(response, status, jqXHR)` set of parameters.